# Adding all class object array values to a text file

Tags: c#

I want to add all properties values assigned during instantiation of Course class into text File.

```
 CourseManager courseMng = new CourseManager();


        Course prog1 = new Course();
        Console.WriteLine(prog1.GetInfo());
        Console.WriteLine();


        prog1.CourseCode = "COMP100";
        prog1.Name = "Programming 1";
        prog1.Description = "Programming1 description";
        prog1.NoOfEvaluations = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(prog1.GetInfo());


        Course prog2 = new Course("COMP123", "Programming2") { Description = "prog 2 desc", NoOfEvaluations = 2 };
        Console.WriteLine(prog2.GetInfo());



        courseMng.AddCourse(prog1);
        courseMng.AddCourse(prog2);
```

This was my main and this is my CourseManager class

```
Course[] courses;
    int numberOfCourses;


    public int NumberOfCourses
    {
        get { return numberOfCourses; }
        set { numberOfCourses = value; }

    }

    public Course[] Courses
    {
        get
        {
            return courses;
        }

        set
        {
            courses = value;
        }
    }

    public CourseManager()
    {
        Courses = new Course[100];

    }


     public void AddCourse(Course aCourse)
    {

        Courses[numberOfCourses] = aCourse;
        numberOfCourses++;
        aCourse.Manager = this;

    }

    public void ExportCourses(string fileName, char Delim)
    {


        FileStream stream = null;
        StreamWriter writer;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            Course aCourse = new Course();
                for(int i =0; i<numberOfCourses;i++)
            {

               //writer.WriteLine(courses.ToString());
                writer.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}{1}{4}", aCourse.CourseCode, Delim, aCourse.Name, aCourse.Description, aCourse.NoOfEvaluations);
            }


            writer.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }


    }
```

So the problem is when i try to writeline it just prints empty values. I want CourseCode,Name,Descrpition and NumberOfEvaluations to be written in .txt file.
If u need any other code please let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is where you are getting your data from in the lines

```
Course aCourse = new Course();
for(int i =0; i<numberOfCourses;i++)
{
    //writer.WriteLine(courses.ToString());
    writer.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}{1}{4}", aCourse.CourseCode, Delim, aCourse.Name, aCourse.Description, aCourse.NoOfEvaluations);
}
```

The issue is you are writing out the values of the properties of `aCourse` which is never set to anything than a `new Course()` (as per the first line).

Try changing it to this

```
for(int i =0; i<numberOfCourses;i++)
{
    Course aCourse = Courses[i];
    //writer.WriteLine(courses.ToString());
    writer.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{1}{3}{1}{4}", aCourse.CourseCode, Delim, aCourse.Name, aCourse.Description, aCourse.NoOfEvaluations);
}
```

In the second example we are setting the value of `aCourse` to be the next course in the iterator.

**As per your comment**

> i have a file with different courses and i want to add it to courses
>   array. I am doing this
>
> ```
> Course C = new Course(); 
> C.CourseCode = reader.ReadLine(); 
> C.Name = reader.ReadLine();
> C.Description = reader.ReadLine(); 
> C.NoOfEvaluations = Int32.Parse(reader.ReadLine()); 
> courses[index++] = C;
> ```
>
> But i am getting invalid input error at NoofEvaluations any solution?

The issue here is you exported the data in a single line via the `writer.WriteLine` method delimiting the values by a delimeter `|` or more exactly by the 'char Delim` paramter. In this case you need to read a single line into an array that is split by the same character. Somthing like.

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();
var array = line.Split('|'); // or char Delim if you prefer
var c = new Course();
c.CourseCode = array[0];
c.Name = array[1];
c.Description = array[2];
c.NoOfEvaluations = int.Parse(array[3]);
courses[index++] = c;
```

Comment: Omg such a silly mistake thanks it solved the problem!! Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked and mark as answer when you test it. Cheers.

Comment: While u are at it can u help me with 1 more problem what i am trying to do in other method is i have a file with different courses and i want to add it to courses array. I am doing this
Course C = new Course();
                    C.CourseCode = reader.ReadLine();
                    C.Name = reader.ReadLine();
                    C.Description = reader.ReadLine();
                    C.NoOfEvaluations = Int32.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
                    courses[index++] = C; 
But i am getting invalid input error at NoofEvaluations any solution?

Comment: Is the delimeter a new line character?

Comment: I am not really good at programming still learninig and i dont want to sound stupid but  i am using Delimeter to split between individual records. I don't know if it means the same as a new line character!!

Comment: can you tell me in the code above when you export the data what is the delimeter (ie char delm). What is the character?

Comment: I am Using '|' "PIPE" as a delim

Comment: @ShivamSood i have updated my answer with the answer to your comment.

Comment: now i am getting array out of bounds exception.
P.S- Sorry to bother u again and again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing your problem, I'm going suggest different code to clean things up. I would simplify as follows:

```
public class Course
{
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NoOfEvaluations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    //this will format the text to your specification
    public string ToDelimitedString(char Delimiter)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{4}{1}{4}{2}{4}{3}{5}"
            , this.CourseCode
            , this.Name
            , this.Description
            , this.NoOfEvaluations.ToString()
            , Delimiter
            , Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public void Export(string FileName, char Delimiter)
    {
        //this will be more efficient than writing on line at a time
        var coursesExport = new StringBuilder();

        foreach(var course in this.Courses)
        {
            coursesExport.Append(course.ToDelimitedString(Delimiter));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(FileName, coursesExport.ToString());
    }
}
```